# Local Policy gets overridden by a GPO

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I my domain I have several SQL servers and I need the **Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy\Audit policy change policy** defined with Success.

I tried defining them locally via Local Policy. Everything seems fine for 20-25 minutes until it gets overridden with **Not Defined**.

My question is how is it possible to get overridden to **Not Defined**?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the SQL Servers members of the domain? why don't you just configure the policies for all sql servers via GPO?

Comment: Yes they are members of the domain. Making a GPO would be an alternative but for the moment I'm not allowed to create one.

Comment: I made a rsop on them and they have no policy defined in Audit Policies. After i change them locally they get overridden to Not Defined. I just don't understand how that is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that one or more of your domain group policies that are enforced on that domain joined computer has the **"Turn off Local Group Policy objects processing"** option enabled. This prevents someone like yourself from modifying the system via the local group policy.

Because domain policies have higher priority than local ones there is no way around what you are asking without having a domain administrator get onboard with your request.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override group policy with a local policy due to the order windows applies them.

1. Local
2. Site
3. Domain
4. OU

If your policy is overridden by a higher level one there is not much you can do.

TechNet source [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: A setting that is `Not Defined` isn't being manage by Group Policy. I'm unaware of any exceptions to this.